How to store the value of a ltmark in a variable for a given page?
I'm continuing my playing with ltmarks (this is not a follow up, but... Using ltmarks for counter ranges in headers) and I think I got things working for my actual use case, and am very pleased with results. However, I have a backward compatibility problem, for which I still couldn't find a solution.
The general setup is something like:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:eeTF { \FirstMark{mymarks} } { \LastMark{mymarks} }
      { Item~\FirstMark{mymarks} }
      { Items~\FirstMark{mymarks}--\LastMark{mymarks} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

This document works as expected, and we get running headers with correct counter values, and singular/plural in order too, as appropriate for each case.
Now, the problem I have is that, currently, I provide equivalent data through user facing public variables, which are updated every shipout/before for the next page based on a somewhat complicated cross-reference data structure. Let's call these variables \mymarkfirst and \mymarklast.
A first idea would be to just set:
\tl_set:Nn \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarklast { \LastMark{mymarks} }

But, while this works for typesetting the marks, it doesn't for the equality test. Because the value of \mymarkfirst and \mymarklast is expected (and documented/public) to contain the actual value of the mark, and when setting them to \FirstMark/\LastMark this is true only after expansion. In other words, the current UI assumes the below should work:
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }

So the indirect setting above to \FirstMark/\LastMark above does not allow us to compare the marks this way, and the test will always be false.
Now the question: is there somewhere where I could set these variables to the expanded value of the marks for a given page and retrieve reliable values? Or, to put it differently, is there a way to retrieve the marks of each page as "data"?
I'm aware that \FirstMark/\LastMark are documented to:

The commands are only meaningful inside the output routine, in other places their result is (while not random) unpredictable due to the way LaTeX cuts text material into pages.

But perhaps in some shipout hook? Or some way to set a label for each page and retrieve the values through a cross-reference?
Edit: Per request in the comments "a non-working example":
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarklast { \LastMark{mymarks} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

What I'm trying to achieve is setting values for \mymarkfirst and \mymarklast with data coming from mymarks such that this definition of \myheader works. This document currently does not work, because the equality comparison fails to distinguish when the value of the marks are equal and thus always typesets the "plural version".

Without example of how you update \mymark… inside shipout/before, I can only guess: Couldn't you use something like a \tl_if_eq:eeTF or \tl_if_eq:xxTF?

@cabohah \mymark... contains the plain number of the "mark" of interest at the time the page is shipped out, just set by other means. And, yes, \tl_if_eq:eeTF or \tl_if_eq:xxTF "would work", the problem is indeed that current UI (and documentation) assumes/recommends using \tl_if_eq:NNTF, so if I now require the variables to be expanded before comparing, I'd be breaking existing documents.

if you update the data in shipout/before, why do you need marks for them at all?

@UlrikeFischer I'm trying to replace the current structure with ltmarks, it is "the right tool" for the task, but it wasn't available in its generalized form back when I released the package. Tests so far went well, so I'd like to go for it, I'm just trying "not to break things" in the process.

I'm not sure I got the problem. You should provide a breaking example.

@UlrikeFischer I thought it was enough, but I now made the "non-working" version more explicit.

why don't you expand your commands as you do it for the other example \tl_if_eq:eeTF {\mymarkfirst}{ \mymarklast} seems to work fine.

@UlrikeFischer Again, because the current UI (and documentation) assumes/recommends using \tl_if_eq:NNTF, so if I now require the variables to be expanded before comparing, I'd be breaking existing documents. These are user facing variables, with an existing current expected behavior.

You don't want to compare the definition of \mymarkfirst and \mymarklast but their expansions. So I don't understand, why you should not use \tl_if_eq:eeTF.

@cabohah I know how to "fix it for me, in my document", the first MWE does that and works. Yet again, the whole problem of the question is that, the current UI of the package for which this is an use case, expects \tl_if_eq:NNTF to work and be sufficient for this comparison. And I'm trying to find a way so that it continues to be, but now supplying the information from the ltmarks data, somehow.

But isn't \myhead your own definition? So why shouldn't you be free to change it? Sorry, but it is absolutely unclear, what can be changed an what cannot.

@cabohah In the MWE, yes... Perhaps I'm making things too abstract. If you're curious enough, see the section "Headers" of texdoc postnotes. You'll see that it is a documented feature of these user facing variables that they can be compared without being expanded first. And if you're even more curious, see the same named section at texdoc postnotes-code for how the variables are currently being set at the shipout/before hook.

The code used by postnotes is different, because there the definitions of \pnhdpagefirst and \pnhdpagelast can be compared. But in your case the expansion of \mymarkfirst and \mymarklast have to be compared. It makes not sense to say: I want to compare something different, but want to use the same command. It makes more sense to say: I use the command, which does the comparison I want.

@cabohah No, I want to set the variable to its expanded value somewhere else, before that comparison takes place. That's why I'm asking how "to retrieve the marks of each page as "data"?"

If you need definitions to be equal, why are you not expanding at the point of assignment? \tl_set:Ne \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }

Doing the expansion somewhere else, before that comparison takes place is exactly, what I've shown in the second example of my answer. Nevertheless, I still think, that it does not make sense or at least that is does not make more sense, than doing the correct comparison.

@JosephWright If you know the place where I can make such assignment, that's what I'm looking for. It would obviously not work to do it globally, though. (I did try the shipout/before and shipout hooks. I'm not sure I got everything right, but it seems I'm getting data of the previous page at that point).

@cabohah Yes, but I simply can't use xpatch on \@outputpage... And, yes, "doing the correct comparison" would be ideal, the problem though is "to avoid breaking existing documents of users".

sorry but I do find the way you fill the header quite curious. Why do you do the test in \markboth? I would setup a suitable header definition.

You cannot do this, you cannot do that. Sorry, but is is very hard to help you. We even do not know, what you can and what you cannot and why you think, you cannot to this and cannot to that. You need to do the expansion in the header and AFAIK there isn't a suitable hook already existing. So either use a suitable page header definition, that contains the expansion or you need to patch it into the usage of the header definition.

@UlrikeFischer The current structure was the way I found to make things work in the absence of ltmarks, the relevant variables are set every page at the shipout/before hook and, since the values of the variables are only meaningful after that, doing the comparison in \markboth was something which seemed reasonable. Maybe it is not "the best way" to do it. But it is how the UI currently works.

@cabohah Sorry for dumping unreasonable requirements on you. ;-) And thanks for looking into the problem regardless.

You could at least show an example that shows, how the question is related to package postnotes. Currently this is completely unclear.

I've added one more example without using xpatch. But maybe you are also unable to use this for one more currently unknown reason.

@cabohah Once again, thank you. But I won't tap into the kernel's internal \@outputpage directly. The use case is a published package, as I've mentioned. So I'm only willing to use public interfaces for the purpose. Maybe this makes you a bit mad now, but if you are ever on the user side of one of my packages, you may get to appreciate the policy which is, btw, nothing special, just "sensible". ;-)

The ltproperties based approach below seems reasonable, and appears to produce correct results, at least for the MWE in the OP:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\property_new:nnnn { myfirstmark } { shipout } { } { \FirstMark { mymarks } }
\property_new:nnnn { mylastmark  } { shipout } { } { \LastMark  { mymarks } }
\cs_set_eq:NN \mymarkfirst \prg_do_nothing:
\cs_set_eq:NN \mymarklast \prg_do_nothing:
\AddToHook { shipout/before }
  {
    \property_record:ee { mymarks@ \int_use:N \c@page }
      { myfirstmark, mylastmark }
    \protected@xdef \mymarkfirst
      { \property_ref:ee { mymarks@ \int_use:N \c@page } { myfirstmark } }
    \protected@xdef \mymarklast
      { \property_ref:ee { mymarks@ \int_use:N \c@page } { mylastmark  } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \myheader } { }
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

However, I'm not really sure enough about the timing of things, and would appreciate some thoughts from those better acquainted with the OR. And, if anyone has better ideas, it is still most welcome, of course.

I still would recommend to use
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarklast { \LastMark{mymarks} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:eeTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

and as long as \myheader is your own definition, I don't see why this shouldn't be done.
However, if you want, you can move the corresponding change to a (more or less ugly patch) to avoid the change of your own definition of \myheader:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }
    
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@outputpage}{{\@thehead}}
  {{
    \tl_set:Ne \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }
    \tl_set:Ne \mymarklast { \LastMark{mymarks} }
    \@thehead
  }}
  {}
  {\undefined}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}

or something similar without using xpatch, because in a comment you said, that you cannot use that package:
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewMarkClass{mymarks}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \testitems {}
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { 20 }
      {
        \stepcounter{mycounter}
        \item[\themycounter]\InsertMark{mymarks}{\themycounter} \lipsum[1-3]
      }
  }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarkfirst { \FirstMark{mymarks} }
\tl_set:Nn \mymarklast { \LastMark{mymarks} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\myheader}{}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \mymarkfirst \mymarklast
      { Item~\mymarkfirst }
      { Items~\mymarkfirst--\mymarklast }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\expandmymarks}{}
  {
    \tl_set:Ne \mymarkfirst { \mymarkfirst }
    \tl_set:Ne \mymarklast  { \mymarklast  }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
% remove \begingroup from \@outputpage
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter \@outputpage
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter   {%
  \expandafter\@gobble \@outputpage
}
% add \begingroup \patchevenoddhead at begin of \@outputpage
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@outputpage \expandafter{%
  \expandafter\begingroup \expandafter\patchevenoddhead \@outputpage
}
\newcommand*{\patchevenoddhead}{%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/@oddhead/before}{\expandmymarks}%
  \AddToHookNext{cmd/@evenhead/before}{\expandmymarks}%
}
\makeatother

\DebugMarksOn

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\markboth{\myheader}{\myheader}

\begin{description}
\testitems 
\end{description}

\end{document}


cabohah, I appreciate you looking into this. Thank you. But somehow it seems I'm failing to explain to you the problem I'm trying to solve. And, unfortunately, "ugly patch" is not in the menu for the purpose.
